# How to write low-precision numbers (2-10 bits) to an array buffer / blob?

Tags: javascript, blob, arraybuffer

problem: in video-games there are tons of low precision numbers that can be packed together over the network to dramatically save bandwidth compared to sending strings. Strings are allocated to UTF-8 which uses 1 byte for each character.

Ideally there should be a way to write these numbers together:

- player id in game- precision **0-1023** range, **10 bits**
- player rotation- quaternion- a few numbers ending up as **24 bits** after some math simplification
- player inputs- **0-1** range x2, **2 bits**

How do you take low precision numbers like this and put them in a array buffer / blob?

Comment: *"Strings are allocated to UTF-8 which uses 1 byte for each character."* Or two, or three, or four, depending on the character. For instance, `ç` (as in François) is two bytes in UTF-8, as are `£` (the Pound Sterling sign) and `¥` (yen); `€` (the Euro sign) is three bytes.

Comment: Notice that the total number of bits in OPs example is 36 which makes this problem a little more complicated (if compact storage is the goal, that is).

Comment: yes and the numbers have to align properly despite bit shrinkage too, so some method to ensure a fixated length is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Uint32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array), and then use bit shift and mask operations to store values in that array.

For example, if you wanted to store a 4 bit number, and then a 10 bit number (leaving 18 bits left over for more fields):

```
array[0] = (num0 & 0x0f) << 0) |
           (num1 & 0x3ff) << 4);
```

and to extract those fields:

```
num0 = (array[0] >>> 0) & 0x0f;
num1 = (array[0] >>> 4) & 0x3ff;
```

The array can be accessed as an `ArrayBuffer` for serialisation by accessing its `.buffer` property.

Comment: do you mean use bit mask to add values, then bit shift the number of bits assigned to slide it over? Because bitwise operators are still 32-bit and I'm assuming that's the only way to gracefully remove the preceding zeros

Comment: you should still use fixed width fields, but just use as many bits as are required to store the full range of the number in question.

Answer (score 1):

based on Alnitak's answer:

```
function binPush(arr, i, num, max) {
     arr[i] = arr[i] << max.toString(2).length; //shift int32 $max (in base 2) bits to the left to allow for allocation
     arr[i] |= num; // OR bitwise operation, which copies the 1s from $num

}

var myArr = new Uint32Array(1);

binPush(myArr, 0, 3, 3);     // push 11:       00000000000000000000000000000011
binPush(myArr, 0, 10, 15);   // push 1010:     00000000000000000000000000111010
binPush(myArr, 0, 120, 127); // push 1111000:  00000000000000000001110101111000
binPush(myArr, 0, 120, 255); // push 01111000: 00000000000111010111100001111000
```

notice how the last `binPush` adds an extra 0 to the front because the max is 255, which is exactly **8 bits** whereas 120 is **7 bits**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha2oaoeb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps MathewBarker's [bit-stream](https://github.com/MatthewBarker/bit-stream) could be of some help, here.